# How to fix Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet error when calling Move or Delete

Tags: c#, office-interop, excel-interop

I'm trying to move some worksheets around inside a workbook parented by an excel app whose visibility is set to false. I get the following two errors, respectively, when I try to move or delete sheets, respectively:

1. "Error moving sheet in workbook.”
2. "HRESULT: 0x800a03ec"

In the code below, I use a template worksheet which I copy in the destinationWorkbook for each sheetName in requiredSheets (the name changes in each loop).

After I add a worksheet, I attempt to move the worksheet to a specific location (to preserve the correct order of the tabs). Once I exit the loop, I attempt to remove the template sheet from the workbook.

The code is hitting the two exceptions above when I call Move(int index) and Delete() in the code below. These two methods eventually call down into Ms.Interop's Move(before object, after object) and Delete(). I have debugged via dotPeek and ascertained that the two Ms.Interop methods are the ones responsible for throwing the two errors above.

Interestingly, if, during the debugging session, I set the visibility of the Excel App to "true", the code is able to run past these two lines of code without problems.

```
foreach (string sheetName in requiredSheets)
{
     // Skip if the sheet already exists
     if (_destinationWorkbook.Worksheets.Contains(sheetName)) { continue; }

     // Check if the sheet name is actually valid
     if (!_destinationWorkbook.Worksheets.IsValid(sheetName)) { throw new NotImplementedException(); }

     // Create required sheet
     var newWorksheet = destinationWorkbook.CopySheetToThisWorkbook(templateWorksheet, sheetName);
     sheetsAdded++;
     newWorksheet.Move(templateWorksheet.Index + sheetsAdded);
}

if (!requiredSheets.Contains(templateWorksheet.Name))
{
     // If we don't need the template then delete it
     templateWorksheet.Delete();
}
```

Intuitively, I believe these two errors may be related, given they both disappear when the visibility of the excel app is set to 'true'.

Googling the error messages above has not been very fruitful. I am wondering  whether anyone has more insight on what the likely cause were for the unusual behaviour mentioned above.

Solutions to this are also very welcome.

Thank you

**EDIT:**

A slight confusion in the original post was thinking I am getting two separate, but related errors. Error #1 above is simply a wrapper around an inner exception that is Error #2. So in reality I am getting the same error when calling Move/Delete in MsInterop.

The underlying code which calls the MsInterop Move and Delete is:

**Move**

---

```
public void Move(int index)
 {
  bool flag = false;
  if (index < 0) index = 0;
  else if (index >= this._worksheets.Count())
   {
    flag = true;
    index = this._worksheets.Count() - 1;
   }
  Worksheet worksheet;
  try
  {
    worksheet = (Worksheet) this._worksheets[index];
  }
  catch (ArgumentOutOfRangeException ex)
  {
   throw new ExcelWorksheetException((IWorksheet) this, "Error moving sheet in workbook.", (Exception) ex);
  }
  try
  {
    if (flag)
      **this._msWorksheet.Move(Type.Missing, (object) worksheet.GetMsObject());**
    else
      **this._msWorksheet.Move((object) worksheet.GetMsObject(), Type.Missing);**
  }
  catch (COMException ex)
  {
    throw new ExcelWorksheetException((IWorksheet) this, "Error moving sheet in workbook.", (Exception) ex);
  }
```

The run enters the else block and fails when calling Move on the MsInterop.Worksheet.

**Delete**

---

```
public void Delete()
{
  if (this._worksheets.Count() == 1)
    return;
  this.ExcelApplication.DisplayAlerts = false;
  this.ExcelApplication.EnableEvents = false;
  **this._msWorksheet.Delete();**
  this._worksheets.Remove(this);
  this.ExcelApplication.DisplayAlerts = true;
  this.ExcelApplication.EnableEvents = true;
}
```

The run fails when calling .Delete()

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of possible reasons why you may get the specified error at runtime. But I'd suggest starting from the following changes:

1. Use `Type.Missing` parameter for optional ones:

```
newWorksheet.Move(templateWorksheet.Index + sheetsAdded, Type.Missing);
```

2. This issue could take its place if you are using a backward-compatible sheet (a .xls) instead of a .xlsx
3. Try to make changes manually and make sure no issues are visible from the end-user perspective.
4. It is not clear where and when you are trying to automate Excel. Be aware, Microsoft does not currently recommend, and does not support, Automation of Microsoft Office applications from any unattended, non-interactive client application or component (including ASP, ASP.NET, DCOM, and NT Services), because Office may exhibit unstable behavior and/or deadlock when Office is run in this environment.

If you are building a solution that runs in a server-side context, you should try to use components that have been made safe for unattended execution. Or, you should try to find alternatives that allow at least part of the code to run client-side. If you use an Office application from a server-side solution, the application will lack many of the necessary capabilities to run successfully. Additionally, you will be taking risks with the stability of your overall solution. Read more about that in the [Considerations for server-side Automation of Office](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/257757/considerations-for-server-side-automation-of-office?wa=wsignin1.0%3Fwa%3Dwsignin1.0) article.

Comment: 1# I've edited my question to include the decompiled code  that is calling the MsInterop methods. Turns out  Type.Missing was included in the calls to Move(..)

Comment: 2# The excel files involved are .xlsx

3# The changes are possible to be made manually. In fact, they are performed successfully via automation as long as the excel app is visible.

4# The code is being run on my local machine,but I take your point on automation.

Answer (score -1):

No easy way around this, and while not an ideal answer, a solution would be to place a try-catch around the problematic method and try executing it again. For me, it works on the second attempt.